# Force React Navigation to wait for new page is fully loaded before navigating to it?

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-navigation

First of all, I use react navigation's stack navigator in a very customized way. I basically always replace the current route with a new one using `navigation.replace()`, because my app have almost limitless route possibilities with different parameters, and I want't to preserve full navigation history, which is not possible when using `navigation.navigate()`, and without keeping all the routes in memory (app becomes very laggy after 10+ different routes in memory).

So, I have also custom function for going back in navigation history, it takes the previous route and parameters from array of custom route objects, and those objects contains also last scroll position for each route.

I have a `ScrollView` on each page, and when going back I set the scroll position for it in `useEffect` hook. Page is fully rendered when react navigation opens it, but sometimes it is not yet scrolled to correct position before showing, and it does not look good when page is at position 0 when loaded then it suddenly jumps to correct position.

So finally the question: React Navigation renders the page before navigating to it, but is there any way to tell to React Navigation that now it can be shown (it is loaded and I have handled scrolling to correct position)? So basically I need a way to tell when the page is ready. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is to animate to the current position. I don't think there is another way.

Comment: That's the alternate way, if there really is no other way. It looks kind of good on iOS, but on Android the scroll animation is pretty ugly as it's very fast.

Comment: Are you using flatlist, did you try initialScrollIndex ?

Comment: I'm using ScrollView...